# How can I optimize the memory usage of mysql server on ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I have an ubuntu server version 20.04.2 LTS.
On it I have installed just mysql version 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

It's a dedicated server so I have my.cnf set up as this:

```
innodb_dedicated_server = 1
skip_name_resolve       = 1
key_buffer_size         = 16M
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
max_binlog_size         = 100M
```

The server is a vmware VM configured with 10GB RAM, 8 CPU (2 core, 4 sockets).

The problem is this; every now and then (once in a day or every 2 days) mysql crashes saying "out of memory". For example, just a moment ago I checked my free memory with free -m and it was 130.
I thought probably is normal because of innodb_dedicated_server. I have run an alter table on a table with 3.5 million rows and that's when it crashed. Probably it did not have enough memory for the alter table.

How can I optimize this? I would like it to use as much memory as possible but I don't want it to crash for an alter table...

Any help?
Thanks!

EDIT:

as pointed out, I have moved the discussion here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/1069556/how-can-i-optimize-the-memory-usage-of-mysql-server-on-ubuntu

Comment: This is not a coding question. Please ask those type of questions over at https://serverfault.com or https://superuser.com

Comment: It sounds like the rest of the VM is being used by other applications.  Also, what is the value of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';`?

Comment: 'innodb_buffer_pool_size', '8589934592'